# Android Factory Reset

Tags: factory-reset

After a factory reset on my Note 5 the first step after selecting language Google requires is the previous email account entry, I've entered my gmail account and password 10 times and it keeps telling me to use the original. It is the original. Except for an updated password. It is an endless loop; how do you get out of it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are completely positive that that email is correct, try these things:

1. Resetting the password to the original (if you know it).
2. Make sure you're using a Google account (Or Gmail).
3. Contacting your service provider's help line or contact support.
4. Contact Samsung [here](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/supportMain.do.).

Good Luck. I would recommend contacting Samsung **BEFORE** your service provider.

Comment: 1. Tried that, didn't work

Comment: 2. Only email account I use regulary is gmail. 3. Going to service provider to get a new phone after I finish typing. 4. Samsung - no thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something wrong here. When you enter your Google Account credentials, there you will be asked to enter email and password. Once that is filled, in the next screen you will be asked to type your recovery email. That's it. Only the recovery email, Google doesn't ask password for it.

You did something wrong.

Anyways, you can change your email password right now. Here is the official Google guide - https://support.google.com/mail/answer/41078?hl=en

Comment: I wish that were true, the message I get after entering my google account credentials and having them accepted is: "This device was reset. To continue, sign in with a Google Account that was previously synced on this device." Over and Over and Over ; like I said stuck in a loop.

Comment: Sorry prior to the aforementioned quotation for a brief instant this message flashes on the screen: "Please sign in using one of the owner's accounts." Note: 1. When purposely entering the wrong password you get: Wrong password. Try again." 2. When purposely entering the wrong Google Account name you get: "Couldn't find your Google Account" Following that thread lands you right back where I started!

Comment: Perhaps your issue is complicated and unique. Have you tried logging in with that gmail account on PC? Is that working? And if you are familiar with Recovery mode, then you can factory reset your phone that way. Sometimes there might be cache files that might be causing the issue. So hard reset via recovery mode might help. Google it and read guide on how to do it. Also you need to wipe of Cache.